# How to build an easy Rails authentication with OpenID and OAuth1.0a-2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, openid, oauth, authlogic

I'am looking for an easy authentication for my users mostly via facebook, but keeping OpenID and other OAuth alternatives as well. For the case if something will go very bad, I will ask my users to optionally provide their email address, which should be obtained via OpenID or OAuth if possible. The same thing is about their name.

I am a newbie in Rails, so I started with Railscasts.com [#160 (authlogic)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) and [#170 (authlogic and OpenID)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic), however, I had some problems trying to sign in with my Google Account. As I understand, it will take some effort to adjust #170 for my objectives. On the other hand, there is gem `authlogic_rpx` which will possibly provide me the needed functionality (see http://rails-authlogic-rpx-sample.heroku.com/signin).

What would you do? Is it reasonable to put one more step (RPX) in the authentication logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an authlogic and declarative_authorization example that I'm adding facebook connect to right now.
http://github.com/jspooner/authlogic_cucumber_rspec_example

This is an authlogic openid example that is 90%.  I hit a bug and haven't had time to check it out.
http://github.com/jspooner/authlogic_openid_example

Hope these examples help.